# How to get packageName from gomobile in android

Tags: android, go, gomobile, prebuild

How to JNICall from gomobile in android

I want to write part of the code of my Android application in the Go library

I want to get the `PackageName` and signature of my app and send it to the server (all this work should be done in `Go` files)

Question :

How can you get the `PackageName and the signature` of the my app in the Go section?